# javascript object private property behaves as if public

Tags: javascript, object, properties, private

As I was trying to show someone public vs private properties in a js object, I got very confused all of a sudden.

Let's take the following object:

```
function person() {
    var name = 'joe';
    var age  = '32';

    this.setName = function (name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    this.setAge = function (age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    this.getName = function () {
        return this.name;
    }

    this.getAge = function () {
        return this.age;
   }
}

var newBuddy = new person();
```

I expect newBuddy.name and newBuddy.age to be undefined at this stage. They are. So far so good!

However, look at the following:

```
newBuddy.setName('matt'); //I use my setName() method to change the name. 
newBuddy.name; // returns "matt" -> that' what I cannot understand. 
// I was expecting not to be able to access this property. Ever. See below.
```

My thought process is:
If I had declared this.name = 'joe' instead of var name = 'joe', I would understand that newBuddy.name returns 'joe' first, then 'matt'. The public property would have been accessible.

But because I declared my property with "var name", shouldn't I not be able to access this property?

My understanding was that the only way to get the name would be by calling my this.getName() method with newBuddy.getName();

To me, in that object, newBuddy.name should always return undefined.

I felt confident using objects until that moment, and I really cannot figure out what I am mising.

I ran that code in my firebug 2.0.2 console using Firefox 31.0, I doubt it makes any difference.

Comment: I got the same results here: http://jsfiddle.net/6xxtwrp8/ I too am curious about this...

Comment: Oh! I know why.. you used `this` in front of the variable names. Don't put `this` on there.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `this`, you already declared local (private) variables for `name` and `age`:

```
function Person() {
  var _name = 'Joe';
  var _age  = 32;

  this.setName = function (name) {
    _name = name;
  }

  this.setAge = function (age) {
    _age = age;
  }

  this.getName = function () {
    return _name;
  }

  this.getAge = function () {
    return _age;
  }
}
```

Comment: Breaking the rule on comments. Just wanted to say thanks guys. That helped a lot. Was getting very frustrated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with how you are assigning/accessing the variables within the getter and setter methods.

```
this.setName = function (name) {
     this.name = name;
}
```

When you set `this.name`, you are creating the property on the `person` instance. If you wish to set the value of the local variable `name`, you simply omit `this`.

ex:

```
this.setName = function (name) {
     name = name;
}
```

This, however, will still not function correctly, as the parameter `name` has the same name as the 'private' property, which means the identifier `name` will always resolve to the parameter `name` instead of the 'private' property. This can be remedied by renaming either the parameter or the private variable. I would simply prefix the private variables with `_`:

```
function person(){
    var _name = "Joe";
    this.setName = function (name) {
         _name = name;
    }
    this.getName = function () {
        return _name;
    }
}
```